# How to stop open Safari when Login Facebook via Parse SDK

Tags: parse-platform, facebook-login, ios9

I am now using parse to set up Facebook login, but it will jump into Safari when I click PFLogInFieldsFacebook button. I want to have a in APP login page(UIWebView or something). I want to do that because I noticed that IOS 9 will give a back to Safari when I am back to my APP. Here is the code I am using:

```
PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
[logInViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate
                // Create the sign up view controller
                logInViewController.fields = PFLogInFieldsFacebook;
                // Present the log in view controller
                [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
logInViewController.logInView.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"allow.png"].CGImage;
[logInViewController.logInView setLogo:nil];
```

I also find that latest Facebook SDK can do the job, but I am still getting used to using Parse. So please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through parse doc, I figured out that AppDelegate.m file should be updated like this for IOS 9:

> There's also two code changes you'll need to make. First, add the
>   following to your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method,
>   after you've initialized the Parse SDK.
>
> ```
> // AppDelegate.m
> #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
> #import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
>
> @implementation AppDelegate
>
> - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
>   [Parse setApplicationId:@"parseAppId" clientKey:@"parseClientKey"];
>   [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
> }
>
>
> Next, add the following handlers in your app delegate.
>
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
>             openURL:(NSURL *)url
>   sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
>          annotation:(id)annotation {
>   return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
>                                                         openURL:url
>                                               sourceApplication:sourceApplication
>                                                      annotation:annotation];
> }
>
> - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
>   [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
> }
> ```
>
> There are two main ways to use Facebook with your Parse users: (1) to
>   log in (or sign up) as a Facebook user and creating a PFUser, or (2)
>   linking Facebook to an existing PFUser.